# Bootstrap carousel not working after data is being updated in Angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, angular7

I have a Bootstrap carousel in my Angular 7 application. I am updating the carousel data in a  fix interval of time. It works for the first time but once the HTTP service updates the slide array, the carousel stops sliding.

This is the code in the component html file "home.component.html":-

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="slides.length > 0" [showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows" [showNavigationIndicators]="showNavigationIndicators">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let slide of slides" [id]="slide.id">

    <app-screen1 *ngIf="slide.type == 'screen1'" [slideData]="slide"></app-screen1>
    <app-screen2 *ngIf="slide.type == 'screen2'" [slideData]="slide"></app-screen2>

  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

This is the component ts file "home.component.ts".:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig, NgbCarousel } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(NgbCarousel)
  private ngbCarousel: NgbCarousel;

  intervalId: any;

  showNavigationArrows = false;
  showNavigationIndicators = false;

  slides = [];

  constructor(
    protected config: NgbCarouselConfig,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {
    config.interval = 2000;
    config.wrap = false;
    config.keyboard = false;
    config.pauseOnHover = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshData();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.refreshData();
    }, 10000);
  }

  refreshData() {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe((result) => {
      this.slides = result;
      // this.ngbCarousel.pause();
      // this.ngbCarousel.
      // this.config.interval = 3000;
    },
    (error) => {

    });
  }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may need to destroy carousel element and then set it again

Comment: this may help https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1562

Answer (score 0):

this is a [working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grxyzr) demo

mocked the service call... but repeatedly calling the service with a simple counter, which you can replace with your own service logic...